# Verify that certain statistic is complete (namely, $X_{(1)}$ for $f_\theta(x)=e^{-(x-3\theta)}I_{(3\theta,\infty)}(x)$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, definite-integrals, statistical-inference

Given the density function of a certain population

$$f_\theta(x)=e^{-(x-3\theta)}I_{(3\theta,\infty)}(x)$$

I am asked to find a complete statistic for a random simple sample $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ of it.

From the nature of the given density function, I would like to prove that $X_{(1)}$ is complete.

To do so, the density of $X_{(1)}$ is given by

$$g(x)=ne^{-n(x-3\theta)}$$

And if $\operatorname E[f(S)]=0$, where $S=X_{(1)}$, then

$$\operatorname E[f(S)]=\int_{3\theta}^\infty f(x)ne^{-n(x-3\theta)}\, dx=0$$

How to proceed from this point, and prove that $f=0$ almost everywhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you need is that that if $\operatorname E[f(S)] = 0$ then the integral you've displayed is $0.$ That is trivial: the value of the integral is the expected value of the random variable $f(S).$ What you need is that if $\operatorname E[f(S)]$ remains equal to $0$ regardless of the value of $\theta$ then the function $f$ is identically $0.$ Or "almost everywhere" $0,$ if you like. $\qquad$

Comment: You have
$$
\operatorname E[f(S)]=\int_{3\theta}^\infty f(x) ne^{-(x-3\theta)}\big(1+e^{-(x-3 \theta)} \big)^{n-1} \, dx=0.
$$
If $u= x-3\theta$ then $du=dx,$ and as $x$ goes from $3\theta$ to $\infty,$ then $u$ goes from $0$ to $\infty,$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty f(u+3\theta) n e^{-u} \left( 1 + e^{-u} \right)^{n-1} \, du.
$$
Now the question is: If that integral remains equal to $0$ as $\theta$ varies, does it follow that $f$ is (almost) everywhere $0 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: How would that be done without identifying $f$ as some particular function?

Comment: Let's do a further substitution: $w = 1+ e^{-u},$ $dw = -e^{-u}\, du,$ so the integral becomes: $$ \int_1^0 f(3\theta - \log(w-1)) w^{n-1} (-dw). $$ The question then is: If _that_ remains equal to $0$ as $\theta$ varies, can one deduce that $f$ vanishes almost everywhere? $\qquad$

Comment: ERRATUM: I should have said this: $$ \int_2^1 f(3\theta - \log(w-1)) w^{n-1} (-dw). $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the CDF of shifted exponential distribution is 
$$
F_{X_1}(x)=I_{(3\theta,\infty)}(x)\int_{3\theta}^x e^{-(t-3\theta)}\, dt = - e^{-(t-3\theta)} \big|_{3\theta}^x\cdot I_{(3\theta,\infty)}(x)=(1-e^{-(x-3\theta)})I_{(3\theta,\infty)}(x).
$$
It cannot be $1+e^{-(x-3\theta)}$ as assumed in your calculations since this value is greater than $1$, and $F_{X_1}(x)$ is a probability.

Next, the CDF of $X_{(1)}$ is 
$$
F_{X_{(1)}}(x)=1-(1-F_{X_1}(x))^n = (1-e^{-n(x-3\theta)})I_{(3\theta,\infty)}(x).
$$
Finally, the PDF of $X_{(1)}$ is 
$$
g(x)=ne^{-n(x-3\theta)}I_{(3\theta,\infty)}(x)
$$

To prove completeness we need to suggest that for any $\theta\in\mathbb R$
$$
\int_{3\theta}^\infty f(x)ne^{-nx}e^{3n\theta}\, dx =0
$$
and derive that $f(x)=0$ a.e.

Note that multiplier $e^{3n\theta}$ cannot be zero. Therefore
$$
\int_{3\theta}^\infty f(x)ne^{-nx}e^{3n\theta}\, dx \equiv 0 \iff 
\int_{3\theta}^\infty f(x)ne^{-nx}\, dx \equiv 0
$$
Since the last integral equals zero for any $\theta$, we can subtract two integrals for different $\theta$ and get: for any $a<b$
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\int_{a}^b f(x)ne^{-nx}\, dx = 0
$$
If you can apply Radon-Nikodym theorem here, do it and complete. Other case we need to follow the rest way.

Prove that for any Borel set $B$
$$\tag{2}\label{2}
\int\limits_B f(x)ne^{-nx}\, dx = 0.
$$
To do it, let $$\mathcal A=\left\{B\in \mathfrak B(\mathbb R): \int\limits_B f(x)ne^{-nx}\, dx = 0\right\}.$$
We collect into $\mathcal A$ all Borel sets with the property: integrals over these sets are zero.

Prove that $\mathfrak B(\mathbb R)\subseteq\mathcal A$. Indeed, any interval $(a,b)$ belongs to $\mathcal A$ due to (\ref{1}). Next, you can check that $\mathcal A$ is a sigma-algebra. Therefore it contains Borel sigma-algebra since Borel sigma-algebra is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains any interval on $\mathbb R$.

So, the proved (\ref{2}).

Finally, consider Borel sets $B_1=\{x: f(x)>0\}$ and $B_2=\{x: f(x)<0\}$. From (\ref{2}) we have 
$$
\int\limits_{B_1} f(x)ne^{-nx}\, dx = 0 \text{ and } \int\limits_{B_2} f(x)ne^{-nx}\, dx = 0.
$$
If Lebesgue measure $\lambda(B_i)$ is not equal to zero than the first integral is strictly positive, and the second is strictly negative. So, both measures are zero and $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.